# How to make a class that returns an instance without `new` keyword

Tags: javascript, oop

I would like to create a class that would work like for example built in BigInt. So I can do:

`BigInt('111') BigInt('222').toString()`

Please guide me on how to code it. I'm using NodeJS with vanilla JavaScript. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Write a function that creates an object and set all properties, or that returns a class with new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions.

It's probably easiest to create a normal class and then a helper function that creates the object.

```js
class MyRealClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  hello() {
    console.log('Hello', this.name);
  }
}

function creteMyRealClass(name) {
  if (new.target) throw Error("Object should not be called with 'new'");
  return new MyRealClass(name);
}


creteMyRealClass('Alpha').hello();
```

Another option is to use a helper function that calls Object.create

```js
// By declaring an external object with attributes
// common to all objects of this type, you save memory
// and execution time
const MyPrototype = {
  hello() {
    console.log('Hello', this.name);
  },
};

function createMyPrototype(name) {
  if (new.target) throw Error("Object should not be called with 'new'");
  const obj = Object.create(MyPrototype);
  obj.name = name;
  return obj;
}

const b = createMyPrototype('Beta');
b.hello();
```

Comment: This is brilliant mate. Does exactly what I want. Executing:

`createTokenClass('Alpha').hello();
console.log(createTokenClass('Fox'))
`

prints

`Hello Alpha
TokenClass { name: 'Fox' }`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this, you will have to use *[factory functions](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-factory-functions/)* instead of the usual *class constructors*. Here is an example:

```js
function MyBigInt(value) {
    return {
      toString: function() {
        return `My Value: '${value}'`;
      }
    };
  }
  
console.log(MyBigInt('111').toString()); 
// Output: My Value: '111'
```

Comment: This is close to what I want but `BigInt('111')` returns `111n`. This returns just an object with a 'toString' function. How to make it return a some useful value by default.